# Django - Create the equivalent of a "cross-join" query with the Django ORM

Tags: django, orm, join, many-to-many, django-orm

I have two Django models with are related to each other through a many-to-many relationship.

I need to list the cross product of both tables.

Let say for simplicity's sake that the two models are Pizza and Topping.

I would like the query to return something like this:

```
pizza_name    topping
---------------------
all dressed   cheese
all dressed   mushrooms
all dressed   onions
all dressed   peperoni
all dressed   pepper
reddit        cheese
reddit        peperoni
reddit        bacon
reddit        baconbits
```

The amount of data will be very large and I absolutely need to use count and slices so I can't simply iterate a model and treat the data as I go along.

Any idea how I should proceed?

Comment: By *cross join* do you mean that you want to return return `p*t` rows where `p` is the number of pizzas and `t` is the number of toppings? Or do you want to return every (`pizza`, `topping`) pair in the `pizza_topping` intermediary table? The example results you posted suggest the latter.

Comment: what Alasdair said. in other words, the example that you posted is not a cross product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved it by simply iterating on the intermediate table.