# Calculating Combinations using Django ORM (CROSS JOIN)

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I've got three related models: `Process`, `Factor` and `Level`. A `Process` has a many-to-many relationship with `Factor`s and a `Factor` will have one or more `Level`s. I'm attempting to calculate all combinations of `Level`s involved with a `Process`. This is straightforward to implement with Python's `itertools` as a model method, but is somewhat slow in execution speed, so I'm trying to figure out how to use the Django ORM to perform this calculation in SQL.

Models:

```python
class Process(models.Model):
    factors = models.ManyToManyField(Factor, blank = True)

class Factor(models.Model):
    ...

class Level(models.Model):
    factor = models.ForeignKey(Factor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Example: A process `'Running'` involves three `Factor`s (`'Distance'`, `'Climb'`, `'Surface'`) each composed of a number of `Level`s (`'Long'`/`'Short'`, `'Flat'`/`'Hilly'`, `'Road'`/`'Mixed'`/`'Trail'`). Calculating the combinations in SQL would involve building a query by first determing how many `Factor`s were involved (3 in this example) and performing a `CROSS JOIN` of all the levels that many times.

In SQL, this could be accomplished as such:

```sql
WITH foo AS
    (SELECT * FROM Level
     WHERE Level.factor_id IN
        (SELECT ProcessFactors.factor_id FROM ProcessFactors WHERE process_id = 1)
    )
SELECT a1.*, a2.*, a3.*
    FROM foo a1
    CROSS JOIN foo a2
    CROSS JOIN foo a3
WHERE (a1.factor_id < a2.factor_id) AND (a2.factor_id < a3.factor_id)
```

Result:

```
a1.name | a2.name | a3.name
--------------------------
Long    | Flat    | Road
Long    | Flat    | Mixed
Long    | Flat    | Trail
Long    | Hilly   | Road
Long    | Hilly   | Mixed
Long    | Hilly   | Trail
Short   | Flat    | Road
Short   | Flat    | Mixed
Short   | Flat    | Trail
Short   | Hilly   | Road
Short   | Hilly   | Mixed
Short   | Hilly   | Trail
```

Currently, I have this implemented as a method on the `Process` model as:

```python
def level_combinations(self):
    levels = []
    for factor in self.factors.all():
        levels.append(Level.objects.filter(factor = factor))
    
    combinations = []
    for levels in itertools.product(*levels):
        combination = {}
        
        combination["levels"] = levels
        
        combinations.append(combination)
    
    return combinations
```

Is this possible using the Django ORM or is it complex enough that it should be implemented as a raw query to improve speed over the Python code implementation?

There was a similiar question about [performing `CROSS JOIN` in Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7894214/2167797) from several years ago (approx. Django v1.3 it looks like) didn't attract appear to attract much attention (the author punted to just using Python itertools).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
from itertools import groupby, product
    
def level_combinations(self):
    # We need order by factor_id for proper grouping
    levels = Level.objects.filter(factor__process=self).order_by('factor_id')
    # [{'name': 'Long', 'factor_id': 1, ...},
    #  {'name': 'Short', 'factor_id': 1, ...},
    #  {'name': 'Flat', 'factor_id': 2, ...},
    #  {'name': 'Hilly', 'factor_id': 2, ...}]

    groups = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(levels, lambda l: l.factor_id)]
    # [[{'name': 'Long', 'factor_id': 1, ...},
    #   {'name': 'Short', 'factor_id': 1, ...}],
    #  [{'name': 'Flat', 'factor_id': 2, ...},
    #   {'name': 'Hilly', 'factor_id': 2, ...}]]

    # Note: don't forget, that product is iterator/generator, not list
    return product(*groups)
```

If order doesn't matter, then:

```
def level_combinations(self):
    levels = Level.objects.filter(factor__process=self)
    groups = {}
    for level in levels:
        groups.setdefault(level.factor_id, []).append(level)
    return product(*groups.values())
```

Comment: While this isn't a pure Django ORM solution I was hoping for (which appears to not exist as of Django 1.9 anyway), it is significantly faster than the code I was using before (`timeit` has it about 60% faster). For my production dataset, the unordered algorithm is approx 10% faster than the ordered method).

Answer (score 1):

A few years late, this workaround does *not* actually use a `CROSS JOIN`, but it *does* produce the desired result in a *single* query.

Step 1: add a `cross` field to your `Factor` model

```py
class Factor(models.Model):
    cross = models.ForeignKey(
        to='self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

Step 2: link `'Climb'` to `'Surface'`, and link `'Distance'` to `'Climb'`, using the new `Factor.cross` field

Step 3: query as follows

```py
Level.objects.filter(factor__name='Distance').values_list(
    'name', 'factor__cross__level__name', 'factor__cross__cross__level__name')
```

Result:

```py
('Long', 'Flat', 'Road')
('Long', 'Flat', 'Mixed')
('Long', 'Flat', 'Trail')
('Long', 'Hilly', 'Road')
('Long', 'Hilly', 'Mixed')
('Long', 'Hilly', 'Trail')
('Short', 'Flat', 'Road')
('Short', 'Flat', 'Mixed')
('Short', 'Flat', 'Trail')
('Short', 'Hilly', 'Road')
('Short', 'Hilly', 'Mixed')
('Short', 'Hilly', 'Trail')
```

This is a simplified example. To make it more generic, instead of adding the `Factor.cross` field, you could add a new `CrossedFactors` model with two foreignkeys to `Factor`. This model can then be used to define various experimental designs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could try:

```
for process in Process.objects.all():
    # get all levels for current process
    levels = Level.objects.filter(factor__in=process.factors.all())
```